# How to manage dependencies for an R project manually?

Tags: r, package-managers, renv

I'm aware of, and have been looking at, `renv`. The issue is that when using `renv` with `renv::init()` it will scrape through the repo for any `.R` files and add them to the `renv.lock`, which is a (often large) json file.

If I want to add a package manually (such as styler or docopt) this isn't straightforward.

## I disagree with this being closed

Just editing to state that, I think this would be a useful question to have answered

Note - I've added this back in, I also disagree with the previous edit of:

> not accepting the answer of community is bad idea.

Comment: With [rstudio/renv#544](https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues/554), you can add packages to a renv environment one by one: `renv::snapshot(packages = c("styler", "docopt"))`. You need `renv >= 0.12.0-22`, e.g. via `remotes::install_github("rstudio/renv")`. Also I don't think this is opinion-based and therefore I believe it should be re-opened.

Comment: You can also just add dependencies to the file `DESCRIPTION` manually or with `usethis::use_package()`. Then, anyone who uses your project (e.g. git via clone) can use `remotes::install_deps()` to install all required dependencies. This will not use a virtual environment but install them into the global/user library by default.

Comment: Thanks, i agree that this shouldn't be closed, and would like to use renv (not global) as I want to start using similar management for R as is done with Python envs.